# How to use external jar dependency in Java program?

Tags: java, jar, jsoup

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use JSoup in my program. I figured you simply needed to have the .jar file in the same project folder but this is not the case. There is very little info on the subject online.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using jsoup in Atom".

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the following directory structure

```
.
├── Main.java
└── jsoup-1.12.1.jar
```

and this content in your `Main.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://www.google.com";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println(title);
    }

}
```

In order to be able to compile and run your program, you need to have your `jar` in your `classpath`.

Compile your program like this

```
javac -cp .:jsoup-1.12.1.jar Main.java
```

And run it like this

```
java -cp .:jsoup-1.12.1.jar Main
```

I think this is a good reference point to start learning about Java's `classpath`

[Classpath (Java)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))

Comment: This worked thank you. If you have time I would greatly appreciate if you could link an article or something that explains why I need to do this.

Comment: @LeapyNick Just updated my answer, you can find the link there.